# Put zeros in the given index values of a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have arrays

```
A = np.array([
  [1,6,5],
  [2,3,4],
  [8,3,0]
])

B = np.array([
  [3,2,1],
  [9,2,8],
  [2,1,8]
])
```

Doing `a = np.argwhere(A > 4)` gives me an array of position/indexes of values in array A that are greater than 4 i.e. `[[0 1], [0 2], [2 0]]`.

I need to use these indexes/position from `a = np.argwhere(A > 4)` to replace the values in array B to zero at these specific position i.e. array B should now be

```
B = np.array([
  [3,0,0],
  [9,2,8],
  [0,1,8]
])
```

I am big time stuck any help with this will be really appreciated.

Thank You :)

Comment: `B[A > 4] = 0`?

Comment: I don't want to threshold B, I want to threshold A and positions/indexes that are has value less than the threshold has to be made zero in array B.

Comment: That's why you take the mask for A and index it with B. What's the confusion? It gives you what you want.

Comment: Apologies for the simple question .. I am pretty new to python. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
B[A > 4] = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, though, note that the indices returned by `np.where` *are meant* to be applied to `numpy.ndarray` objects, so you could have done:

```
B[np.where(A > 4)] = 0
```

Generally I don't use `np.where` with a condition like this, I just use the boolean mask directly, as in John Zwinck's answer. But it is probably important to understand that you *could*

```
>>> B[np.where(A > 4)] = 0
>>> B
array([[3, 0, 0],
       [9, 2, 8],
       [0, 1, 8]])
```